# different between identifier and type

Tags: java, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

Hi Please I need a help for writing  my java grammar using flex and bison. I have a syntax error when I am trying to return INT as keywords or as Identifier. 
for example: in my flex file. I have the following:

`{int}       {return(INT);} 
 INTEGER             {decimalINT}|{hexINT}|{octalINT}`
`

`{INTEGER}       {`

```
yylval=install(yytext);
 return INTEGER_LITERAL;}
```

In my bison file, I have the following rules that use INT as keyword.

```
TYPE: PrimitiveType|ReferenceType;
PrimitiveType:NumericType||BOOLEAN;
NumericType:IntegralType|FloatingPointType;;
IntegralType:BYTE|SHORT|INT|LONG|CHAR;
```

Then my test file [java program] has this statement :

```
int x=9;
```

I am getting syntax error. However, when I remove INT from  IntegralType  rule, it works with no errors. 
Can anyone find  why that happens?
I believe when I remove the keyword INT from the rule, my parser considers  INT as identifier and processed with no errors.

Comment: Your code is unreadable and incomplete. Please create a [mcve] (which is a small but complete program, not just an excerpt).